# Best way to find all shortcodes that come with WordPress

Tags: shortcode

I am using WordPress 4.6.1.  What tactics can I apply to find all available shortcodes that come with WordPress OOTB.  I am having trouble find this information on the web.  various guides in the codex and outside of it use simple examples like [gallery], but I am curious to knowing what is my full available list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grep the 4.6.1 core codebase for all instances of "add_shortcode".

Alternatively, there is an extension for Debug Bar that will show you all shortcodes:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-shortcodes/

Comment: Thank you!  Through Visual Studio Code I did a search through all files for add_shortcode and my answers showed up!  Funny thing is that there are more now in the latest version of WordPress, then what is posted on the codex.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yup - exactly why I suggested looking in the most current code instead :)

Answer (score 2):

The Codex page has a list of built-in shortcodes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode

Comment: For as fast as wordpress comes out with different versions...I'm not sure to trust the upkeep of the codex.  But thanks

Comment: That's totally fair! I actually think WordPress is in the middle of revamping the codex too, so its a bit more of a mess than usual :)